# Tracking Email Links to Microsoft Office Users

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content, email-tracking

We insert URLs from a Data Extension for our deployments, and all is working as expected - except, when the recipient is using Microsoft Outlook.  In the past we corrected this using the `<!--[if mso]>` code and it was working at some point, but I've just noticed that our links are NOT being tracked.

Here's the partial code as it is now for our button

```
<!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="%%=RedirectTo(@1a_button_URL)=%%" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#00AB99"><w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@1a_button_URL)=%%" style="background-color:#00AB99;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:250px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">%%=v(@1a_button_COPY)=%%</a> <!--[if mso]>
    </center>`
`  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Has MSFT changed?
What are we missing here?